# Show two Different View_Table on PHPMyEDIT

Tags: php, phpmyid

I have the following Two display rendered on one page, but some how the first is showing and the second view is not...why?

```
<?php

    // include all the necessary file
    require_once(PATHS.'lib');

    $opts['title'] = PAGE_HEADER;
    $opts['tb'] = 'v_table_1';
    $opts['key'] = 'ID';

    $opts['buttons']['L']['up'] = $opts['buttons']['F']['up'] = $opts['buttons']['L']['down'] = $opts['buttons']['F']['down'] = array('<<','<','>','>>','goto_combo');

    $opts['options'] = 'F';         // A - add,  C - change, P - copy, V - view, D - delete, F - filter, I - initial sort suppressed

    $opts['fdd']['ID'] = array(
        'name'        => _('ID'),
        'select'    => 'T',
        'options'    => 'AVCPDLFX',
        'maxlen'    => 20,
        'sort'        => true,
    );

    $opts['fdd']['name'] = array(
        'name'        => _('Name'),
        'select'    => 'T',
        'options'    => 'AVCPDLFX',
        'maxlen'    => 20,
        'sort'        => true,
    );
    $opts['fdd']['age'] = array(
        'name'        => _('Age'),
        'select'    => 'T',
        'options'    => 'AVCPDLFX',
        'sort'        => true,
    );
    $pme_table1 = pme_render($opts, true);



    $opts['title'] = PAGE_HEADER;
    $opts['tb'] = 'v_table_2';
    $opts['key'] = 'ID';
    $opts['buttons']['L']['up'] = array('<<','<','>','>>','goto_combo');

    $opts['options'] = 'F';         // A - add,  C - change, P - copy, V - view, D - delete, F - filter, I - initial sort suppressed

    $opts['fdd']['ID2'] = array(
        'name'        => _('ID2'),
        'select'    => 'T',
        'options'    => 'AVCPDLFX',
        'maxlen'    => 20,
        'sort'        => true,
    );
    $opts['fdd']['name2'] = array(
        'name'        => _('Name2'),
        'select'    => 'T',
        'options'    => 'AVCPDLFX',
        'maxlen'    => 20,
        'sort'        => true,
    );
    $opts['fdd']['age2'] = array(
        'name'        => _('Age2'),
        'select'    => 'T',
        'options'    => 'AVCPDLFX',
        'maxlen'    => 50,
        'sort'        => true,
        'required'    => true,
    );
    $pme_table2 = pme_render($opts, true);

    require_once(APP_PATH.'header.php');

?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#table" data-toggle="tab"><?=_('Table1')?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#me" data-toggle="tab"><?=_('Table2')?></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="table">
            <?php
                echo $pme_table1;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="me">
             <?php
                echo $pme_table2;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above code render two tabs and the first tab filed with the first render pme_table1 from v_table_1, But the next view is empty or some times I can see error said "phpMyEdit error: no database defined"? what is this? why not both doesn't display side by side?

some one help....